# kdb \t timer not stopping operation

Tags: kdb

I have a client side function that queries tables on 3 remote servers and pulls in data for each alphanumeric character from each server.

At the end of the function a timer checks the `running` dictionary on each server, and if each character has ran (all dictionary values set to 1b) it should kill the timer and close the connection handle.

However I've discovered that the timer isn't being stopped and after the last character has ran (dictionary values all=1b) the cycle will try to start again, which causes the system to hang.

How can I rewrite my timer function so that it effectively closes the connection handle once the value of `all running` is `1b`?

The last 3 lines of my function look like the following...

```
    f:{
    ...do stuff here...;
    if[hA"all running"; system "t 0";hclose hA;];
    if[hB"all running"; system "t 0";hclose hB;];
    if[hC"all running"; system "t 0";hclose hC;];
    }

    .z.ts:{f params}

    \t 5000
```

`hA`, `hB`, and `hC` are my connecton handles.

`.z.ts` runs the function every 5 seconds.

`params` is grabbing a character from the command line, which is set when the script is started.

I'd like to stop the function from running once the value of `all running` is `1b`.

Comment: You only want to stop your timer after *all* handles have completed their processing right? Not sure why you're setting the timer to zero after a single handle completes processing

Comment: @terrylynch that's correct. Are you suggesting using an `if` statement with `and` values such as `if[(hA"all running")and(hB"all running")and(hC"all running");system "t 0";hclose hA; hclose hB; hclose hC]` ? The other thought I had was moving those if statements to the `.z.ts` function so it would look something like `.z.ts:{f params;if[(hA"all running")and(hB"all running")and(hC"all running");system "t 0";hclose hA; hclose hB; hclose hC]}` .

Comment: Yes that would make more sense - to check all are true before doing anything else. Putting it inside the timer might be a good idea too as it would clean up the `f` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @terrylynch's comment of "stopping the timer after *all* handles have finished processing" - I joined the `if` statements (that stop the timer) into a singular `if` statement and moved it into the `.z.ts` function

```
.z.ts:{f params;if[(hA"all running")and(hB"all running")and(hC"all running");system "t 0";hclose hA; hclose hB; hclose hC]}
```

which upon initial testing seems to work.